# tornado twittermixin couldn't redirect and tornado told me a 500 error

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, tornado

```
class AuthHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.TwitterMixin):
@tornado.web.asynchronous
def get(self):
    if self.get_argument("oauth_token", None):
        self.get_authenticated_user(self.async_callback(self._on_auth))
        return
    self.authenticate_redirect()
    print 1

def _on_auth(self, user):
    if not user:
        raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, "Twitter auth failed")
    self.set_secure_cookie("user", tornado.escape.json_encode(user))
    self.redirect("/")
```

when the terminal print 1 but I didn't get redirected to the authentic url "`api.twitter.com`"
and the browser shows

> 500: Internal Server Error

Tornado told me:

> raise Exception("Could not get request token")
>
> Exception: Could not get request token

Comment: i suppose you need to get `request_token` with the help of which you need to get redirect URL and you exception indicating there is some issue in getting that `request_toke`n from twitter.

Comment: i dont think so. In fact tornado didn't finish the first step of oauth

Answer (score 0):

Your server couldn't connect to http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate to get 'request token' from twitter

Comment: thank you. i have got the reason. I'm a Chinese developer and the Great Firewall blocked the  access to *.twitter.com !